# Can't see output of Web Service on Android device

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I have written a Android code that calls a web service.I now want to run that app on my actual phone and not the emulator. When I run the app using Android Emulator and url http://10.0.2.2/test/Service1.asmx , I get to see my output but when I change the url to http://192.168.56.1/test/Service1.asmx , I cannot see the same output on my Android smartphone.It gives an error saying connection refused.

Please can someone help me solve this problem

Here is the android code:

```
             package projects.ksoap2sample;
             import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
             import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
             import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
             import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
             import android.app.*;
             import android.os.*;
             import android.widget.TextView;

            public class ksoap2sample extends Activity {
              /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";

            private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";

            private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            private static final String URL = "http://192.168.56.1/test/Service1.asmx";
           TextView tv;

           @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
            call();

        }

          public void call()
        {
        try {

          SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new    SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

        tv.setText(result.toString());
         } catch (Exception e) {
        tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
      } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem doesn't reside with your android source since it is obviously working when the network endpoint is available, rather you problem is most likely due to a network restriction causing the endpoint to not be available.

The most common culprit is a firewall, have you ensured that traffic is allowed in/out on the selected port (assumed 80) from the host of the service?

I believe that you are unaffected when running under the emulator because the way the 10.0.0.2 route works makes the system think as though the traffic originated from the host and is probably exempt from any firewall rules in place that would block remote traffic.

Comment: I have no idea about that..Please can u tell me how should I check that the selected port allows traffic ? Any settings need to be done?

Comment: @Parth_90 That is a very broad question honestly because it depends on the types of firewalls in place. I am going to assume because of the `.asmx` extension on the service that the host is a Windows PC using the default windows firewall. In this case you can enable the rule for allowing port80 traffic in and out of the machine. Of course the specific procedure (via GUI) is dependent on the version of Windows you are running but a quick search on Google shows a guide that may be of use: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/

Comment: Yes ur rite.. I am using Windows 7 and I have made the web service using C# in .NET (VS 2008). Also I am using Eclipse for Android app development. Thanks for the link..Will try doing that and reply

Comment: @Parth_90 The settings (hardware or other firewall not-withstanding) are located in Windows under the Control panel, the linked article should direct you on how to add a firewall port exception. Looking over the linked article it should be exactly what you are looking for. You should not need to make any modifications to the AndroidSDK or your application as written.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Yes I followed the link and got the port 80 open. Now do I have to restart my laptop ? or just install the app once again on my phone and try?

Comment: Hey I still can't see the output..Do we have to mentioned the ipv4 address which I have done in code or any other address?

Comment: @Parth_90 Are you still getting a connection refused message?

Comment: @Parth_90 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2456/discussion-between-quintin-robinson-and-parth-90)